# why gl_VertexID is not an unsigned int?

Tags: glsl, unsigned-integer

I am in the process of designing a shader program that makes use of the built-in variable [gl_VertexID](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/gl_VertexID.xhtml):

> gl_VertexID — contains the index of the current vertex

The variable is defined as a **signed int**. Why it is not an unsigned int? What happens when it is used with very large arrays (e.g. a 2^30 long array)?
Does GLSL treat it as an unsigned int?

I want to use its content as an output of my shader (e.g writing it into an output FBO buffer) I will read its content using glReadPixels with GL_RED_INTEGER as format and either GL_INT or GL_UNSIGNED_INT as type.
Which one is correct?

- If I use GL_INT I will not be able to address very large arrays.
- In order to use GL_UNSIGNED_INT I might cast the generated gl_VertexID to a uint inside my shader but again, how to access long array?

Comment: It kind of has to be, `GLsizei` is signed as well. So if you consider the only way to draw a specific number of vertices already cuts off 1 bit, it only makes sense that the vertex ID in GLSL also does so. `gl_VertexID` is not necessarily the element's index (which is unsigned), but can also be the number of the drawn vertex (e.g. 45th vertex out of a *signed* `count` of 999 in your call to `glDrawArrays (...)`).

Comment: Good point! The solution for large array thus is to draw them in chunks and read back the indexes (accounting for possible displacement)
I would accept this solution if you write it as an answer (instead of a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely historical reasons. `gl_VertexID` was first defined as part of the [EXT_gpu_shader4](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/gpu_shader4.txt) extension. This extension is defined based on OpenGL 2.0:

> This extension is written against the OpenGL 2.0 specification and version 1.10.59 of the OpenGL Shading Language specification.

GLSL did not yet support unsigned types at the time. They were not introduced until OpenGL 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if OpenGL might treat the vertex id as unsigned int, but you could most likely create your own (full 32-bit) ID. I have done this some time ago by specifying a rgba8888 vertex color attribute which is converted to an id in the shader by bit-shifting the r,g,b, and a components.

Doing this i also noticed that this wasn't anyhow slower than using gl_VertexID, which seemed to introduce some overhead. Nowadays just use an unsigned int attribute.

Also, i wonder, why would you want to read back the gl_VertexID?
(i did this once for an algorithm and it turned out to be not thought through and now has been replaced by sth more efficient ;) )